# facing problem in whatsapp sharing on mobile from phone's browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on Angular application

I am trying to share my application to the **WhatsApp from Phone's browser**

for that, I used my code below:

```
<a *ngIf="WatsappMobile"  href="whatsapp://send?text='hello we bring fToss http://ftoss.com/test/index.html#/matchcenter for you . Join our contest with refcode {{userData.referCode}}'" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Comment: Show the error!

Comment: @PrashantPimpalewhen I click , watsapp app is not opening

Comment: Any error or have searched for any documentation?

Comment: check this codepen https://codepen.io/qliu/pen/lhqgC